# escape entire column if all of that column's fields are null (or zero)

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any way in MySQL query not to fetch a column if all of it's fields are Null (or Zero)? or any way to remove such columns from the result of query?
For example i have different tables and one may look like this:

```
____________________________________________
| id  | value1  | value2 | value3 | value4 |
--------------------------------------------
| 1   |  3      |  0     |  A     | Null   |
| 2   |  5      |  0     |  B     | Null   |
| 3   |  0      |  0     |  C     | Null   |
| 4   |  9      |  0     |  D     | Null   |
| 5   |  7      |  0     |  Null  | Null   |
| 6   |  9      |  0     |  E     | Null   |
--------------------------------------------
```

I need something like this at the end:

```
__________________________
| id  | value1  | value3 |
--------------------------
| 1   |  3      |  A     |
| 2   |  5      |  B     |
| 3   |  0      |  C     |
| 4   |  9      |  D     |
| 5   |  7      |  Null  |
| 6   |  9      |  E     |
--------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: not really. sql works on a row basis. you want column operations, which is better suited for client-side operations.

Comment: @MarcB can i get the sum of one column fields? and if sum equals to zero then i escape that column in my query?

Comment: no. what if the fields are +1 and -1? +1 + -1 = 0. "oops". you also couldn't do the sum without grouping the fields, which'd hide the other non-zero fields in the rows. your best bet would be to run TWO queries. one to do your "is this column empty" tests, then re-run a normal fetch query and display only the non-empty columns.

Comment: Butt all the values are positive. now what?

Comment: then yeah, a sum would do the trick. but note that `0` and `null` are NOT the same thing in sql.

Comment: that's OK. Thanks Marc

Comment: You can check if there is anything besides `NULL` in `value4`, and based on that use different queries: with 3 or 4 columns.

Comment: Thanks Stoleg. yes that's what i should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can do that with dynamic SQL, but whether you have to proceed with this approach is very questionable.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_select_not_empty(IN tbl_name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = NULL, @cols = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
          'SELECT ''',
          column_name,
          ''' name, COUNT(NULLIF(',
          column_name, ', ', 
          CASE WHEN data_type IN('int', 'decimal') THEN 0 WHEN data_type IN('varchar', 'char') THEN '''''' END,
          ')) n FROM ',
          tbl_name
        )
      SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') INTO @sql
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_name = tbl_name;

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
                 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) INTO @cols FROM (', 
                 @sql, 
                 ') q WHERE q.n > 0'
               );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @cols, ' FROM ', @tbl);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now calling our procedure

```
CALL sp_select_not_empty('Table1');
```

And we get

```
+------+--------+--------+
| id   | value1 | value3 |
+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |      3 | A      |
|    2 |      5 | B      |
|    3 |      0 | C      |
|    4 |      9 | D      |
|    5 |      7 | NULL   |
|    6 |      9 | E      |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, value2, if(v = 0, null, v) value3
from (select id, value2, greatest(v1, v2, v3) v
  from (select id, value2,
    ifnull(value2, 0) v1,
    ifnull(value3, 0) v2,
    ifnull(value4, 0) v3
    from mytable) x
  ) y
```

This first turns all nulls to zero, then gets the max of all values, then turns any zeroes to null.